# How can I store complex form in cache memory or local server

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, caching

I have a requirement to store data some where other than the database. My form contains 3 Object records. Basically in constructor first record is displaying I am entering data into that after that I am adding more record ands related child records by clicking buttons. I want to store data and reuse those in case of  current/or internet issue . I don't want to enter the same data again.

Can any one suggest an idea about how can I solve this without touching the Salesforce Database?

Answer (score 1):

For me it's a bit unclear, what you're asking.

First to cache local is a possible solution - not a requirement. Your requirement is to reuse input data somehow. Therefore you need not to cache at all, at least in my humble opinion.

**Server side caches**

A server side cache you may create with a custom object and possibly one or many long text fields to hold up some JSON or whatever cache data model you want to use. There is no out-of-the-box caching mechanism in salesforce, because it's usually not necessary.

**Client side caches**

There are two things coming into my mind: good old cookies and local storage. Both of them are accessible via JavaScript and you should simply google for more details. Cookies are quite old and limited in size. Local storage (what I'm using from time to time) have less restrictions and can hold up a large amount of data: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html - Since even the development with local storage is easier, I would recommend to forget about cookies.

**Why at all?**

As far as I understood your process - where you description is abstract and very short - you fill in a complex form with one or more master-records, each of them may contain additionally none or many child records.

Now the implementation details of what and how happens there would be crucial to give you good advice. I assume, that at some point in time you commit the form to the salesforce database "somehow".

If this assumption is right, generally speaking, you need no cache but you need only to be able to select what was committed and clone it. Either you can figure out a SOQL to do so or you can mark those records somehow.

But all that is only blind guesswork unless you describe precisely your datamodel and process together with source code of what you already have.